# PHP regex to replace words starting with @ end ending with 2 spaces

Tags: php, regex, laravel-blade

In PHP, how do I strip all double spaces directly behind a word starting with an @ (at) symbol?

Example input:

```
This is  an @example  input.
```

Example output:

```
This is  an @example output.
```

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Comment: Do you lose anything by replacing any multiple inline spaces with a single space? https://eval.in/775818

Comment: Hint: use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match a word beginning with a `@`, reset matching output, match more than one whitespace afterwards then do a replacement:

```
preg_replace('~@\w+\K\s{2,}~', ' ', $input_string);
```

Regex explanation:

```
@\w+    # Match a `@` fowlling a word
\K      # Reset matching process output
\s{2,}  # Match double or more whitespaces
```

[PHP live demo](https://3v4l.org/H2I8b)